# Can't find recently viewed Contacts in Global Search

Tags: global-search

I'm a Sys Admin, and one of my users is saying that when she uses Global Search to search for Contacts, most of the time it is **not** working.  The examples she has given work fine for me when I try and search in Global Search.  One such contact was created back in January, so it should not be an indexing issue.  She can view the Contact via some other means (I gave her the URL to navigate to the Contact directly), but a subsequent Global Search after viewing it still fails to find it. So it's not an access issue.  In the left sidebar where it shows the numbers of matches, it clearly says "Contacts (0)".  So it's not an issue with the types of objects Global Search is setup for.  I checked a couple of SFDC Articles which address this(https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_crowding_considerations.htm&type=5, https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Object-not-included-in-search-and-results-differ-for-users&type=1), but neither seemed to show anything that might be the cause. So I seemed to have eliminated all the usual causes for this.  Are  there some other potential causes I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

- Is the contact private (has no `AccountId`)?
- If you click "Sharing" button on the contact (assuming your OWD isn't "controlled by parent") & expand the list - can you see this user all right on the list?
- Does she have the Contacts tab on in her app (clutching at straws here)
- Are there some contacts that do work?
- Is her user's locale set to Hungarian, Chinese, Korean, Japanese? These cultures work in "Lastname Firstname" format.
- really stupid idea: any chance you have a custom object labeled "Contact" ;)

Comment: Tried to add Sharing button to the Contact page, but it did not allow me to because sharing setting for Contact is "Controlled by parent".  So looked at the sharing for parent Account, and saw that it's 'Associated record owner or sharing', and it shows that the user owns some Opps whose parent is the Account.  This in turn allows the user to view Contacts of the same Account.  In addition, global search did not work for parent Account either.  So looks like a "feature" which makes global search not find records which the user has access to via 'Associated record owner or sharing'

Comment: Never heard about such limitation, you might want to simply raise a ticket with SF. If you're right - other than explicitly sharing the Account (apex managed sharing? adding her as team member? just manually make an entry in "Sharing" to test the hypothesis) I don't think you can modify the search behaviour... Can you also try tips from https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000iRC0QAM ?